# Laravel 8 schedule via cron on AWS EC2 linux - commands not running

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, cron

I've created a cron job in AWS EC2 but it is not working at scheduled time.when i run command in cli php artisan schedule:run it is working fine but not execute automatically at scheduled time.

php version=7.4.3

php Framework = 8

**I added cron entry in crontab using crontab -e**

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

[image]

**/var/www/html/app/Console\Kernal**

```
  /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('booking:cron')->everyMinute();

    }

       /**
         * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $commands=[
            '\App\Console\Commands\BookingCron',
        ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an unwanted `cd` in your cron command, it should be

```
* * * * * /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Bro i have updated but it's not working.

Comment: how can i check error in logs ? if it is not working

Comment: You can run the exact same command `/var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` and see what it says

Comment: will i have to use without hash ?

Comment: please help me it's not working

Comment: Everything with a hash is a comment, so yes without a hash. And you would have to specify a schedule, how often do you want it to run? 5 * means every minute

Answer (score 0):

I think there is missing php command

```
 * * * * * php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```